# Alert pattern to handle repetitive tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

**Context**

I m actually developping an application in which people have tasks to make in a day. It's just like "wash the window, clean the floor" etc.. etc...

Each task has a recurrence, and needs to be done at least one time in this period.

*Example* :

Task 1 has to be done every 15 days. Actually, it's been 16 days that it has not been done. So an event should be emitted.

My client needs to be alerted when something *hasn't been done* , on a time event, with a proper manner

I know that cron tasks exist for this, I could run one at midnight everyday, and send a mail alert with this. But what if I need to be exactly 15 days ? seconds by seconds ?

I really need efficiency without running this kind of scripts every days.

Does it exist a better way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of working with timed events in Javascript is through [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

You should keep in mind that the interval size parameter of the function is a 32-bit integer, which limits its size to `2147483647`.

This parameter is given in miliseconds, so your maximum interval is about 24 days (`2147483647 / (1000 [ms in a sec] * 3600 [secs in an hour] * 24 [hours in a day]`).

All you have to do is:

```
setInterval(function(){
    doWhateverYouNeedHere();
}, interval);
```

## Edit

You could workaround the interval size parameter by stacking recursive [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) calls with a lower interval:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        doWhateverYouNeedHere();

        setTimeout(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                doWhateverYouNeedHere();
            }, not_so_big_interval);
        }, not_so_big_interval);
    }, not_so_big_interval); // max 24 days
}, not_so_big_interval); // max 24 days
// In total, your function will run every 48 days.
```